# Pandas Groupby with Aggregates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am working with pandas and I was wondering if there is a difference based on which statistical functions are applied as shown in the below examples and if there are certain situations where one is preferred over another.

1. `df.groupby('A')['B'].agg('min')`
2. `df.groupby('A')['B'].min()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the code give the same desired output. But the `agg` function is more versatile in terms of the number of functions to apply.

For example, you can do the following with `agg`

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(['min', 'max', 'mean'])
```

Another difference is that, applying a single function i.e. `min` will give you a `Series` in your case and the output of `agg` can either be a `Series` or a `DataFrame`

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, there is no difference between them, cause, the underlying function is `np.min`

```py
def min(self, numeric_only: bool = False, min_count: int = -1):
    return self._agg_general(
        numeric_only=numeric_only, min_count=min_count, alias="min", npfunc=np.min
    )
```

`npfunc=np.min`

Comment: The code from `pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py`